# Changing main image source on product page in magento

Tags: php, image, magento, media, product

I need to change the way main image on product page is loaded (there is only one image) and make it be loaded from external url.

Now: image is loaded from media folder on my server.

Need: image is loaded from external url without being saved on my server

I have created an additional attribute "externalimg". Its value is eg "https://images.otto.de/is/image/mmo/12489608?$001PICT30$"
I tried editing media.php file which for some reason deliver no changes at all, even if I delete it from server. I use a custom theme.
I did this with catalog images and it worked fine. All products have different images, so changing base media path didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I have now found out that with default magento theme changing media.phtml works fine. With my theme "yummy" it does not work. Any changes in media.phtml are just ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to override `/app/design/frontend/yournamespace/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`

If it doesn't exist, copy it from base into your theme folder at the correct path.

However, your theme may also use an extension that is over-writing this default template file.  You should be able to use something like https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints to find the correct template, or simply find some specific HTML around the product image and then search your source code to find the relevant section to alter.